# MPMoviePlayerController not working in iOS4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios4

I'm using the first answer from
[iOS 4 + MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130363/ios-4-mpmovieplayercontroller)

to try and get `MPMoviePlayerController` to play.  In the simulator (iPhone device with iOS4), I hear sound but no video.  On the device (iPhone 3GS and iOS4), I don't get anything.  Here's my code:

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(view)]) {
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }

    [moviePlayer play];
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tested the following code on iOS4 + iPhone 4 (and a 3GS)—it works fine. At first blush, I *think* your code's problem is not calling `setFullscreen:animated` on your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance.

```
- (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
}

- (void)enteredFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"enteredFullscreen");
}

- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");
}

- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");
    [self.movieController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.movieController = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Ended");         
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: Playback Error");
            break;
            case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            NSLog(@"playbackFinished. Reason: User Exited");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    [self.movieController setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)showMovie {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    NSURL* movieURL =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tron" ofType:@"mov"]];
    self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    if ([self.movieController respondsToSelector:@selector(view)]) {
        self.movieController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
        [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
        [self.movieController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }
    [self.movieController play];
}

// This method is set as the action for an on-screen button
- (void)movieTime:(id)sender {
    [self showMovie];
}
```

Comment: Not working on iOS4 with iPhone 3GS.  In the debugger, it gets to the self.movieController.view.frame line and skips over the next two.

Comment: If I read that correctly, you're saying execution gets to the first line *inside* the if block but skips the next two? Seems highly unlikely. Let me dig out one of our 3GS testing units...

Comment: ... yep, works here with a 3GS running iOS4. One thing that may make a difference is the context—in my app that code is called from an event handler, not in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I've edited my original answer with all the related code from the `UIViewController` instance.

Comment: Thanks.  Now when I put your updated code in, I get an error on self.view.  The file I'm in is of type NSObject.  it is called from a UIView.  Does the NSObject file need to create a view to put the video player on?  Also, where are you disposing of all the player allocs?  I alloc every time a video is played.

Comment: All of this code expects to be in a `UIViewController` subclass. If your code is in a subclass of `NSObject`, that's been the problem since the start.

Comment: Ah.  I want to contain all of the movie management to a class.  Is there a way to keep it in the class and still be able to use it?  Or does it have to get spread out into the UIViewController?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, just pass the view you want to embed to your movie management class (or provide an accessor that lets other classes get at the movie's view member.)

I'm just saying that there is no self.view member if you're not in a subclass of UIViewController and that's why none of my code or your original code is working.

Comment: Do you know of a way I can tests that this will work on iOS3?  There isn't a simulator for iOS3 in xcode.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the Video file format itself?  Are there formats that play on newer devices but not on older ones?  I'm having a problem where a video plays back no problem on an iPod/iPhone 4G but not on older devices.  The MPMoviePlayerViewController is pushed, says Loading Movie, then returns immediately.

Comment: @Art Gillespie, hey friend this is working. thank you so much. i have tested in ios6

Answer (score -4):

For `MPMoviePlayerController` `view` is a property, not a method, so you can't use `respondsToSelector:` on it if it doesn't have methods synthesized or written for it (i.e. is declared @dynamic). Which I think is true for most readonly properties in UIKit.

Comment: Any @property will have a corresponding getter method.

Comment: Obviously not, as `respondsToSelector:` will always return false with dynamic properties.